# opencart guest checkout giving undefined index g-captcha-response error

Tags: php, opencart2.x

ok so im new to opencart and im a noob to coding. I recently installed opencart and I keep getting this error. when i try to register or use guest checkout. the continue button also becomes inactive and changes to "loading..."
i am using Version 2.1.0.2. i was using the version before this one and decided to update because of the same error.

**error is as follows:**

> SyntaxError:Unexpected token <
>
> OK **Notice**:Undefined index:g-recaptcha-response in **/home3/
>   mydirectory/catalog/controller/captcha/google_captcha.php** on line
>    **32** {"error":{"captcha":Verification code does not match the
>   image!"}}

[guest undefined index error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuRJ7.jpg)

additionally when I disable google recaptcha all goes fine.

[image]

-----Edit--------
here is the code snippet from line 32

```
$recaptcha = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($this->config->get('google_captcha_secret')) . '&response=' . $this->request->post['g-recaptcha-response'] . '&remoteip=' . $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Please help

Comment: Did you checked the following file and following line?

Comment: yes u did but since im a complete noob i coudnt figure out what is wrong with the code. I edited my post to enter a nippet of line 32 of the file.